# É possivel criar uma versão de App diferente para cada versão do android?

Tags: android

Tem componentes que não são suportados em versões anteriores do android, porém tem alternativas a eles. Tem alguma forma de manter componentes ideais para as versões ideais e as alternativas para aquelas versões que não a suportam?

Comment: Acredito que não tenha como fazer de uma forma simples, talvez vc tenha de criar projetos diferentes, contendo os códigos que vc deseja para cada versão do android. O mais simples é utilizar os 2 códigos e separá-los nas versões que deseja considerar em cada uma. Para isso crie uma classe Utility e nos pontos chave, realize a validação: `public static boolean isAndroidMarshmallowOrSuperiorVersion() {
        return Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M;
    }`

Answer (score 3):

É possível, nem que seja criando um projecto para cada versão.

O principal problema dessa abordagem é a repetição de código.,

Esse problema pode ser evitado usando outra abordagem: [Variantes de compilação](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/index.html).

As variantes de compilação são conseguidas recorrendo à capacidade do Gradle usar regras especificas para definir combinações de código, recursos e configurações para gerar compilações diferentes de um mesmo projecto.

As possibilidades são várias, das quais destaco as seguintes:

- [Tipos de compilação](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html#build-types).
- [Variações de produtos](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html#product-flavors).
- [Entradas do manifesto](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-merge.html).
- [Dependências](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html#dependencies).
- [Divisões de APK](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits.html).

Referências:

- [Configure sua compilação](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/index.html).
- [Configure variantes de compilação](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html).

<sub>Nota: As [bibliotecas de suporte](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/index.html) resolvem a maioria dos casos que refere sem a necessidade de recorrer a variantes de compilação.</sub>